# How to read multiple csv files dynamically with jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to read multiple csv files from a specific folder using Jmeter

Until now I read one csv file and I could loop it with a thread that runned X times when X- is the number of lines in the file.
I was counting the number of lines in the csv file before the thread with a bean_shell like that:

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
String DirPath = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(DirPath + "/files/App1.csv"));
LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
int linenumber = 0;
while (lineReader.readLine() != null){
linenumber++;
}
props.put("rowsnumberApp", Integer.toString(linenumber));
```

Now, I want to read multiple files from a folder, when the amount of files in the folder can dynamically change,

The files names will be like that:

app1

app2

app3

app...

I have this code to read all files from the folder:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
String DirPath = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
File folder = new File(DirPath + "/files");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
int counter = 1;
for (File file : files) {
    vars.put("file_" + counter, file.getAbsolutePath());
    counter++;
}
```

Each file has different amount of lines (but at least I have the same soap-request for all of them)

I realized that using a loop controller on csv gives only the first line.

And as you can see I already have the code part for reading files from a folder and counting the number of lines,

I just need a way to connect all of this to be able to loop for all csv files in the folder

so any idea?

Comment: You want loop for every file dynamically?

Comment: yes, and each file has different amount of lines

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 Loops, first save how many files by:

```
vars.put("fileLength", files.length);
```

Create first Loop with ${fileLength} as loop count

Add Counter start with 0 Maximum ${fileLength} Increment 1 Reference Name cnt

Inside loop read as your first beanshell change to use counter

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(DirPath + "/files/file_" + vars.get("cnt")));
```

Update your current implementation with the counter:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
String currentFileIndex = vars.get("cnt");
String DirPath = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(DirPath + "/files/file_" + currentFileIndex ));
LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
int linenumber = 0;
while (lineReader.readLine() != null){
linenumber++;
}
props.put("rowsnumberApp" + currentFileIndex , Integer.toString(linenumber));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution will read just the first line from each file desn't it?
when I tried to loop on one csv file with a loop controller it read just the first line

Comment: No, you have a script to read all lines It will be called inside a loop for every file

Comment: How should I use this script?

Comment: so I should use
loop for amount of files in the folder->

     loop for each file->

             loop for the amount of lines in the file->
                       my soap->


and each loop should be of type: "Loop controller"
did I understand you correctly?

Comment: ok thank you Ill try it and Ill update here if it works soon
Thank you

Comment: Hi when I'm trying to loop for a csv file by the amount of lines with loop controller it's still read just the first line

Comment: Can you post your test plan? I think 1 loop controller is enough because you are looping in beanshell code

Comment: with bean shell i just get the information about the number of files and the number of lines in a file, it doesn't go parallel with the loop

Is there a way to communicate with you via email or some chat?

Comment: Second beanshell should be inside loop because it uses the counter DirPath + "/files/file_" + currentFileIndex ));

Comment: yes I know, i put it inside the loop.
but even if you take for example a simple loop controller that runs for the number of lines it still will read just one row

Answer (score 0):

[Directory Listing Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DirectoryListing/) plugin would be the easiest option to proceed

[image: Directory Listing Config Example]

This way you will get a single JMeter Variable which you will be able to use in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to parameterize your API calls

See [Introducing the Directory Listing Config Plugin on JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) for more details.

You can install the Directory Listing Config Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter Directory Listing Config]

Comment: When i'm trying to use the thread and for example i put in thread property: "number of threads" the number of the files and in the thread property: "loop count" I put the number of lines i want to be read, so theres times that it not loop all files, and it seems very randomalic so i would love if you could add some example